# Cannot get query param in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have this proxy-middleware application. It is not including express.js.

Server.js contains this:

```
const app = require('connect')(),
http = require('http'),
```

While the middlewares a set of rules, for example:

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
HttpProxyRules = require('http-proxy-rules'),
  const proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
    rules: {
  '/api/v1/stuff/([0-9]+)/documents/': 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/$1',
  },
default: 'http://localhost:4443'
});
```

So all the other microservices are being intercepted by this proxy.
There is an "app.use" where a few checks are made.
Here I can see the request-object. Im interested in reading the query parameter attached to the url.
So when I have this:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1.1/stuff/63/documents/file.pdf?token=mytoken
```

Printing this:

```
console.log('GATEWAY',req.originalUrl);
```

Will output this:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1.1/stuff/63/documents/file.pdf?token=mytoken
```

However, how can I access the query parameter? As Im not using express, doing "req.query" gives undefined.
I have tried a bunch of solutions: "querystring", "url" etc. But they give very strange result and it is not easy to get the field itself. I can never do something like:

```
req.query
```

I had a look at connect documentation but there is nothing about getting the request query parameters.
What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you used the followings:
If not, please add them:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

And try to get req.params

Comment: Installed body-parser with npm. Added this in server.js: const bodyParser = require('body-parser');app.use(bodyParser.json());app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); But then in proxy-middleware both req.query and req.params are undefined.